# Mr. A will bear all the expenses incurred OR Mr. A will incur all the expenses. Did I correctly use the word 'incur'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

1. Mr. A will bear all the expenses incurred during the process of making the new Bill Book.
2. Mr. A will incur all the expenses during the process of making the new Bill Book.

Did I use the word 'incur' properly in the above sentences? Which one is relevant or correct?

**Context:**

Mr. A lost the vehicle bill book and we need to inform and take approval from Sr. Officer to make a new Bill book from the government office. We also need to state that Mr. A will be paying for the expenses from his own pocket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is correct for your desired meaning: Mr. A will be responsible for paying all the costs associated with making the new Bill book.  So if Mr. B orders a new book, and Mr. C drives 10 miles to pick it up, Mr. A will pay for the book and the travel expenses.

Option 2 is also a valid sentence, but it does not have the same meaning; in this sentence, Mr. A will personally perform all the spending.  Mr B. will not order the new book, Mr. A has to do that.  Mr. C will not go pick it up, Mr. A has to do that.  However, since there is no mention of who is ultimately responsible for the actual payment, when all is said and done, Mr. A might still be able to submit an expense report and get the company to pay for everything.

Answer (score 3):

Number 1 is correct but number 2 is not. But #1 is a little wordy. We don't need "during the process of" because the progressive tense already conveys the idea of process.

*Mr A will bear all expenses incurred in making the new Bill Book.*